# Como deixa um alinhamento Span para direita

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap-4

Vamos la, quero deixar o alinhamento do span a direita, mas não estou conseguindo

meu codigo abaixo:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="max-width: 60rem;">Campeonato Brasileiro Série D</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card border-light mb-3" style="max-width: 60rem;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="card-title">Rodada 8 - 15:00 <a href=""><span class="badge badge-success">TEMPO REAL</span></a></h6>
            <br>
            <p class="card-text">
                <img src="img/caucaia.png" width="30" height="30"> <b>Caucaia<span class="align-right">1</span></b><br><br>
                <img src="img/fluminense-pi.png" width="30" height="30"> <b>Fluminense-PI <span class="text-right">1</span></b>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-light"><center><a href=""><span class="badge badge-success">Acompanhe em tempo real</span></a></center></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Quero deixa aonde esta o placar do lado direito e o logo do clube e no nome para a esquerda.

Answer (score -3):

A tag center está deprecada. Terias que adicionar a seguinte propriedade css:

```
<a href="" style="float: right">
```

Comment: A pergunta é sobre bootstrap, talvez a solução seja `<span class="float-right">Texto</span>` ou a solução seja obtida manipulando o sistema de grade, mas em todo o caso o código da pergunta não deixa claro qual o caminho seguir. Referências https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/ e https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score -3):

Pelo visto está usando bootstrap...
Eu faria algo assim:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="max-width: 60rem;">Campeonato Brasileiro Série D
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="card border-light mb-3" style="max-width: 60rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="card-title">Rodada 8 - 15:00 <a href=""><span class="badge badge-success">TEMPO
                        REAL</span></a></h6>
            <br>
            <div class="card-text d-flex">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <img src="img/caucaia.png" width="30" height="30">
                    <b>Caucaia<span class="align-right">1</span></b>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <img src="img/fluminense-pi.png" width="30" height="30">
                    <b>Fluminense-PI <span class="text-right">1</span></b>
                </div>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-light d-flex justify-content-center">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="badge badge-success">Acompanhe em tempo real</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

E como o amigo disse ali, a tag  está em defasada, evite de usar ou terá problemas em breve.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).